# using pandas to create new col in exsisting tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so i have 2 data frames:

```
    1.raw_user = 
    'row_num', 'user_id', 'name', 'review_count', 'yelping_since',
       'ever_been_elite?', 'average_stars'
```

and

```
    2.raw_review =
    'review_id', 'user_id', 'business_id', 'date'
```

I am trying to create a new column in the raw_user table 'latest_review'
which means for each user to save the date of his last review

```
raw_user['latest_review'] = np.nan
raw_user['user_id'] = raw_user['user_id'].astype(str)
raw_reviews['user_id'] = raw_reviews['user_id'].astype(str)

raw_user.loc[raw_user['user_id'] == raw_reviews['user_id'], 'latest_review'] = raw_reviews.groupby(
    ['user_id']).date.transform('last')
```

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: If the two frames have the same number of rows try this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-series-objects/). If not then perhaps a merge is needed.

Comment: how can i do it with merge? they dont have the same num of rows and some of the users in the raw_user table arent exsisting in the raw_review table...any idea what can i do?

Comment: You can use the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function. When you want to find only the keys that exist in both you need to do an `inner`. If you want `NaN` in the result for keys that are not available you can do `left` or `right` join.